# Use XmlData to update table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a stored procedure to update 2 columns `CongTrinhCD` and `CongTrinhTC` in my `BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien` table like this:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[cust_BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien_Luu]       
   @XmlData ntext      
as      
begin      
  declare @iDoc int ,@ReVal int          

  BEGIN TRANSACTION        

    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc output, @XmlData      

    update BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien  
    set  BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien.CongTrinhCD = a.CTCD,     
         BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien.CongTrinhTC = a.CTTC  
    from (      
      select   
          MaQuanLy as MaQL,CongTrinhCD as CTCD,CongTrinhTC as CTTC    
      from openxml(@iDoc,'Root/BangPhuTroi') 
      with (MaQuanLy varchar(20),CongTrinhCD int,CongTrinhTC int)            
   ) a      
  where BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien.MaQuanLy= a.MaQL     

  set @ReVal = @@error      
  if(@ReVal<>0)        
   begin        
    rollback tran        
    return        
   end         
 commit tran        
 select @ReVal        
 return        

end
```

When I execute the stored procedure with parameters:

```
exec dbo.cust_BangPhuTroiGioDay_GiangVien_Luu
        @XmlData=N'<Root>
                       <BangPhuTroi MaQuanLy="70100G05.000015" CongTrinhCD ="50"
                              CongTrinhTC="10"></BangPhuTroi> 
                       <BangPhuTroi MaQuanLy="70100G07.000015" CongTrinhCD ="70"
                              CongTrinhTC="20"></BangPhuTroi>
                       <BangPhuTroi MaQuanLy="70100G07.000052" CongTrinhCD ="80" 
                              CongTrinhTC=""></BangPhuTroi>
                   </Root>'
```

I hope my result after when update is:

```
MaQuanLy="70100G07.000015" CongTrinhCD ="70" CongTrinhTC="20"
```

but result is more like this:

```
MaQuanLy="70100G05.000015" CongTrinhCD ="50" CongTrinhTC="10"
```

I don't know why? Can help me? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're looking at the correct row? The MaQuanLy values are different between the two rows.

Comment: I'm sure.I want it update the last row in xmlData.But it only update the first row.Can you help me?